# SystemNavigationManagerPreview does not exist in current Context

Tags: c#, uwp, package, manifest

So I wanted to try to disable the "X" (Close) Button in my UWP app. For testing I created a new UWP app. I then went to my Visual Studio projects:

\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\closerequesthandled\closerequesthandled

and opened `Package`and edited following things:

First I added `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"` and `rescap`

```
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

Then I added `<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/>`

```
<Capabilities> 
<Capability Name="internetClient" /> 
<rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose"/> 
</Capabilities>
```

I get this warning:
[image: I Get Following warning]

But I read that this warning does nothing besides warning you so it still should work out.

Then I added this as a test to the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SystemNavigationManagerPreview.GetForCurrentView().CloseRequested += this.OnCloseRequest;
    }

    private void OnCloseRequest(object sender, SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs e)
    {
        var x = 0;
    }
}
```

But `SystemNavigationManagerPreview` and `SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs` gets a red underline:

```
The name `SystemNavigationManagerPreview` does not exist in the current context
```

and

```
The type or nmespace name `SystemNavigationCloseRequestedPreviewEventArgs` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Are you using all the right Packages and namespaces?

Comment: I tried "using Windows.UI.Core.Preview" but it also gets a red underline saying Im missing a reference. - How can I check if I have the right package?

Comment: I should have the right Package.

Comment: What version of the Windows SDK are you targeting? This API was introduced in 15063, so if you are targeting an earlier version it would explain the error you are seeing.

Comment: Minimum Version: Windows 10(10.0; Build10240) - Target Version: Windows 10(10.0; Build 10586) // Do you mean this? I only have the option of those 2 targets. How do I get more options? And can I change it on an already created project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the same [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b3947747-4902-42cb-a89a-7e8757878b09/disable-8220x8221-close-button-in-titlebar?forum=wpdevelop) on MSDN. From your folder we noticed that you are using Visual Studio 2015, and Visual Studio 2015 only support to 14393 SDK. As Stefan and my MSDN post mentioned, you have to set your min target version to 15063 first, then you can use the Windows.UI.Core.Preview API. So Visual Studio 2017 is required here for this specific feature.